# Is there a Firefox addon that allows creating new tabs containing only text (like todos) via the address bar without causing any Internet calls?

Tags: web-browser, firefox, todo

I'd like to create Firefox tabs that only contain text but no website by entering the text directly into the address bar.

Is there a way to have this type of tab? This would be similar to entering *about:performance* by which afaik no website or DNS is being looked up either.

It seems like this isn't possible with vanilla Firefox so is there a Firefox addon that allows for this?

For example an addon that allows entering the text after a specific letter or keyboard combination and then just displays the text and nothing else in the new tab page (with a specific favicon and the text set as title).

I'm not looking for Firefox addons for todos or for writing text in the browser - I'm looking for an addon that displays the tab just like any other tab except that it does not contain a website but some text.